# HUGE memory leak when returning std::map<std::string, int> from dereferenced iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, freeze

****Be careful****, not only does this program hang, but apparently it takes *all* of your memory forever, rendering your computer a slow and awful mess. I've been struggling with this for a real long time, and have figured out a lot of things—except for why it actually hangs. Sorry that there's so much code, but I cut out everything irrelevant and this is what was left.

**LinkedList**

```
//=====================
// Linked List

#include <stdexcept>

template<class T> struct LinkedList {
    public:
        LinkedList();
        LinkedList(const LinkedList& srcList);
        ~LinkedList();

        void addObject (T& addedObject);

        class ListIterator {
            public:
                ListIterator();
                explicit ListIterator(LinkedList<T>& parentList);

                // Operators
                ListIterator& operator++();
                T& operator*() const;
                bool operator!=(const ListIterator& otherIter);

            private:
                typename LinkedList::Node* current_;
        };

        ListIterator begin();
        ListIterator end();
        std::size_t size_;

    private:
        struct Node {
            Node();
            Node(T& object);
            Node(const Node&) = delete;
            T* const object_;
            Node* next_;
            Node* prev_;
        };

        Node head_;
        Node tail_;
};

//====================
// Classes (Implementation)

// Linked List default constructor 
template<class T> LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() 
: size_{0} {
    head_.next_ = &tail_;
    tail_.prev_ = &head_;
};

// Linked List copy constructor
template<class T> LinkedList<T>::
LinkedList(const LinkedList& srcList) { 
    size_ = srcList.size_;
    head_.next_ = &tail_;
    tail_.prev_ = &head_;
    ListIterator nodesToCopy = srcList.begin();

    while (nodesToCopy != srcList.end()) { 
        this->addObject(*nodesToCopy);
        srcList.removeObject(1);
    };
    delete &srcList;
};

// Linked List destructor
template<class T> LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList() {
    for (unsigned int ii = 1; ii == size_; ++ii) {
        Node* toDelete = head_.next_;
        head_.next_ = head_.next_->next_;
        delete toDelete;
    };
};

// Add object to Linked List
template<class T> void LinkedList<T>::addObject(T& addedObject) {
    Node* node = new Node(addedObject);
    node->prev_ = tail_.prev_;
    tail_.prev_->next_ = node;
    tail_.prev_ = node;
    node->next_ = &tail_;
    ++size_;
};

// Linked List Iterator constructor
template<class T> LinkedList<T>::ListIterator::
ListIterator(LinkedList<T>& parentList) {
    current_ = parentList.head_.next_;
};

// Iterator operators
// Increment forward
template<class T> typename LinkedList<T>::ListIterator& LinkedList<T>::
ListIterator::operator++() {
    current_ = current_->next_;
    return *this;
};

// Return object pointed to
template<class T> T& LinkedList<T>::ListIterator::
operator*() const {
    return *(current_->object_);  
};

template<class T> bool LinkedList<T>::ListIterator::
operator!=(const ListIterator& otherIter) { 
    return &(**this) != &(*otherIter);
};

// Return an iterator object via begin() and end()
template<class T> typename LinkedList<T>::ListIterator
LinkedList<T>::begin() {
    ListIterator beginIterator(*this);
    return beginIterator;
};
template<class T> typename LinkedList<T>::ListIterator
LinkedList<T>::end() {
    ListIterator endIterator(*this);
    for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < size_; ++ii) { ++endIterator; }; 
    return endIterator;
};

// Node constructors
template<class T> LinkedList<T>::Node::Node()
: object_(nullptr), next_(nullptr), prev_(nullptr) {};

template<class T> LinkedList<T>::Node::Node(T& object) 
: object_(&object) {};
```

**Item**

```
//=====================
// Item
//====================
// Included dependencies
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class Item {
    public: 
        Item();
        Item(std::string name);
        Item(std::string name, std::array<int, 2> stats);
        std::map<std::string, int> getStats();

        std::string name_;

    private:
        std::map<std::string, int> enhancements_;
};

// Constructors
Item::Item() { 
    enhancements_["Str"] = 0;
    enhancements_["Def"] = 0;
};

Item::Item(std::string name) : Item::Item() { name_ = name; };
Item::Item(std::string name, std::array<int, 2> stats)
: Item::Item(name) {
    enhancements_["Str"] = stats[0];
    enhancements_["Def"] = stats[1];
};

// Return map of stats
std::map<std::string, int> Item::getStats() { return enhancements_; };
```

**Room**

```
//====================
// Room
class Room {
    public:
        void addItem(Item item);
        LinkedList<Item>::ListIterator getItems();
        LinkedList<Item> itemsInThisRoom_;
};

// Add item to room
void Room::addItem(Item item) { itemsInThisRoom_.addObject(item); };

// Get iterator which iterates over items in room
LinkedList<Item>::ListIterator Room::getItems() { 
    return itemsInThisRoom_.begin(); 
};
```

**main**

```
int main() {
    std::array<int, 2> swordStats = {{5, 0}};
    std::array<int, 2> shieldStats = {{0, 2}};
    std::array<int, 2> armorStats = {{0, 3}};

    Item sword("Sword", swordStats);
    Item shield("Shield", shieldStats);
    Item armor("Armor", armorStats);
    Room room;

    room.addItem(shield);
    room.addItem(sword);
    room.addItem(armor);
    LinkedList<Item>::ListIterator roomItems = room.itemsInThisRoom_.begin();

    while (roomItems != room.itemsInThisRoom_.end()) {
        (*roomItems).getStats();
        ++roomItems;
    };

    return 0;
};
```

All of this can be put in a single file and compiled (I split it up by class to make it easier to read). This is the line, in *main*, where it hangs:

```
(*roomItems).getStats();
```

This leads me to believe there's something wrong with my dereference operator, right? If we create an iterator *outside* of the Room class, dereference it, and *getStats* the same way—everything works ok.

... so it's an issue with the Room class?

But, if we change *Item* and *main* to the following:

```
//=====================
// Item
//====================
// Included dependencies
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class Item {
    public: 
        Item();
        Item(std::string name);
        Item(std::string, int);
        int getStats();

        std::string name_;

    private:
        int enhancements_;
};

// Constructors
Item::Item() { 
    enhancements_ = 0;
};

Item::Item(std::string name) : Item::Item() { name_ = name; };
Item::Item(std::string name, int stats)
: Item::Item(name) {
    enhancements_ = stats;
};

// Return map of stats
int Item::getStats() { return enhancements_; };

//====================
// Room
class Room {
    public:
        void addItem(Item item);
        LinkedList<Item>::ListIterator getItems();
        LinkedList<Item> itemsInThisRoom_;
};

// Add item to room
void Room::addItem(Item item) { itemsInThisRoom_.addObject(item); };

// Get iterator which iterates over items in room
LinkedList<Item>::ListIterator Room::getItems() { 
    return itemsInThisRoom_.begin(); 
};

int main() {
    Item sword("Sword", 1);
    Item shield("Shield", 2);
    Item armor("Armor", 3);
    Room room;

    room.addItem(shield);
    room.addItem(sword);
    room.addItem(armor);
    LinkedList<Item>::ListIterator roomItems = room.itemsInThisRoom_.begin();
    while (roomItems != room.itemsInThisRoom_.end()) {
        (*roomItems).getStats();
        ++roomItems;
    };

    return 0;
};
```

Everything runs excellently. I can return *int* values alright.

... so... it's neither an issue with the Room class or the dereference operator, but *returning* std::map? GDB does not have much to say. When I break at the offending line and step, I get:

```
24  std::map<std::string, int> Item::getStats() { return enhancements_; };
(gdb) step
_Rb_tree_impl (__a=<optimized out>, __comp=..., this=0x7fffffffced0)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:474
474         _M_header(), _M_node_count(0)
(gdb) step
475       { _M_initialize(); }
(gdb) step
_M_initialize (this=0x7fffffffced0)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:484
484         this->_M_header._M_left = &this->_M_header;
(gdb) step
485         this->_M_header._M_right = &this->_M_header;
(gdb) step
_Rb_tree (__x=..., this=0x7fffffffced0)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:674
674     if (__x._M_root() != 0)
(gdb) step
_M_root (this=0x7fffffffd048)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:498
498       { return this->_M_impl._M_header._M_parent; }
(gdb) step
_Rb_tree (__x=..., this=0x7fffffffced0)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:674
674     if (__x._M_root() != 0)
(gdb) step
676         _M_root() = _M_copy(__x._M_begin(), _M_end());
(gdb) step
std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, int> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, int> > >::_M_copy (
    this=this@entry=0x7fffffffced0, __x=0x619f10, 
    __p=__p@entry=0x7fffffffced8)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:1207
1207          _Link_type __top = _M_clone_node(__x);
```

... which is gibberish to me. :( It does this infinitely, so I know that it (somehow) describes the hangup.

I've got *no* clue what's going on here, haha. I'm very new to C++, and have struggled with this since I woke, so for all I know my code is terrible and I should feel bad for writing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Copying something is not supposed to destroy the original.

Comment: Seems to be a copy and paste from an external source. That external source should have instructions about compiling

Comment: @AjayKulkarni No, this is all my own code. That is a compliment, though. ;)

Comment: Seems like a lot of code. Could you reduce it a bit to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to what's already been mentioned, your `Node` object nonchalantly stores a pointer an object passed from outside by reference

```
template<class T> LinkedList<T>::Node::Node(T& object) 
: object_(&object) {};
```

However, the reference arguments you pass to the constructor of `Node` are actually bound to *local variables*

```
template<class T> void LinkedList<T>::addObject(T& addedObject) {
    Node* node = new Node(addedObject);
    node->prev_ = tail_.prev_;
    tail_.prev_->next_ = node;
    tail_.prev_ = node;
    node->next_ = &tail_;
    ++size_;
};

void Room::addItem(Item item) { itemsInThisRoom_.addObject(item); };
```

i.e. the reference is bound to parameter `item` which is a local variable inside `addItem`.

That local variable `item` is destroyed as soon as `addItem` exits. Your `Node::object_` pointers remain pointing nowhere.

Considering the amount of gratuitous copying you perform in your code, it is completely unclear how you managed to come up with the idea to store a pointer to a non-owned object inside your `Node` (instead of gratuitously copying the entire data into the `Node`, as you do virtually everywhere else).

Anyway, the memory ownership is completely broken in your code, which leads to object lifetime issues as the one above. You need to design some meaningful memory ownership plan from scratch, and then write your code following that plan. What you have now is nonredeemable mess.

If you want to use pointers and you don't think you're ready to untangle this mess, just use smart pointers and let them handle things for you.

P.S. And drop that nasty habit of placing a `;` after each and every `}`.

Comment: Haha! That was it: I was passing *item* by value and not by reference!!! You have no clue how relieved I am! I'm not surprised that the memory ownership is broken—this is my first foray into memory-stuff (and, really, my first venturing into C++). Is there something you can recommend in terms of some good memory-ownership-plan material? Does one usually sit down and draw out a map? (I had the "map" in my head—but apparently it didn't work out.) Or even, maybe, some other suggestions regarding this particular memory-ownership?

Comment: I tried to copy when I thought an object should *have* w/e other sub-object (like the head_ and tail_ nodes being a *part* of the linked list). Is this too literal an interpretation of things? Also—why would this show itself as an issue for returning std::map, but not returning an int? Also, why would it *not* SEGFAULT and instead just do *something* infinitely?

Answer (score 1):

From `template<class T> LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const LinkedList& srcList)`

```
delete &srcList;
```

Really? Just removing this line will improve your code. `&srcList` is not necessarily an address that has been allocated on the heap. And in any case a copy constructor should not be deleting the original.

From `template<class T> LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()`

```
for (unsigned int ii = 1; ii == size_; ++ii)
```

This loop has no effect unless the size of the list is one, it should be

```
for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < size_; ++ii)
```

Comment: This should be at most a comment. It doesn't appear to be related to the question.

Comment: If the OP's really trying to `delete` a local object, this could easily be *directly* related to the question.

Comment: @AnT Could be. An answer should connect the dots. This comes off as random advice with little rationale. `&srcList` could well always be on the heap, by the way, but it `delete &srcList` would still be incorrect.

Comment: @Potatoswatter All I'm hoping is that my answer is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the tips—but neither of these things solved the leak. :( I 100% thought the loop suggestion would; you should have heard me, "OH GOD NO WAY DON'T TELL ME THIS IS ALL IT WAS!!!" My reason for destroying the original is that I wanted to effectively *move* the Linked List and not actually ever copy it (it has a particular use in a larger program). Should I just delete the copy constructor and use '&' to move?

Comment: @AmagicalFishy You could define the move constructor `LinkedList(LinkedList &&src)`. It should not allocate or delete anything, but only initialize the pointer values from `src` and set pointers in `src` to `nullptr`. However, why not just use `std::list`?